# Opening a url in background in service

Tags: android, service

I have a normal service which is supposed to open a url wait 8 sec and open it again. I have set up a handler to do so. Now i have to open a url in the background so it doesn't open a browser window. WebView is no good as it has to have a "window" (not sure how to call it, a window in the ui). How could this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by "open a url" in this context?  Are you looking to download the html contents or is it that url represents REST api for example?

Comment: It's just a simple link to a website on my wifi network. Nothing to download just open it

Comment: When the link is opened it triggers a relay.